# Azure PIM Role Settings for Owner role

Tags: azure, terraform, pim

Trying to set Azure PIM Role Settings for owner role via terraform includes Azure MFA, Activation hours, and also send notifications when eligible to activate this role via local_exec provider in terraform.

I tried this one:

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment""pim_subscription_owner"{
    scope="/subscriptions/<sub id>"            
    role_definition_id ="/subscriptions/id/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/<sub           id>
    principal_id=<principal_id>
    lifecycle{
    ignore_changes=[
    role_definition_id,
    principal_id
    ]
    }
    }
    resource "azurerm_role_assignment""mfa_role_assignment"{
    scope=azurerm_role_assignment.pim_subscription_owner.scope
    role_definition_id="/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/"
    principal_id=azurerm_role_assignment.pim_subscription_owner.principal_id
    provisioner "local_exec" {
    command = <<EOT
    az ad sp mfa set --id ${azurerm_role_assignment.mfa_role_assignment.principal_id) --auth-type      MFA
    EOT
    interpreter=["bash","-c"]
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure PIM Role Settings for Owner role

There is no direct way via `Terraform` to update the `Azure PIM` role settings, but you can use a **PowerShell** script inside Terraform by using `null_resource`.

Here is the `PowerShell` script that updates the `PIM` role settings, such as justification and `MFA` requirement on activation.

**PIMRole.ps1**

```
    $params = @{
        "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.unifiedRoleManagementPolicyEnablementRule"
        id = "Enablement_EndUser_Assignment"
        enabledRules = @(
            "Justification"
            "MultiFactorAuthentication"
            "Ticketing"
        )
        target = @{
            "@odata.type" = "microsoft.graph.unifiedRoleManagementPolicyRuleTarget"
            caller = "EndUser"
            operations = @(
                "All"
            )
            level = "Assignment"
            inheritableSettings = @(
            )
            enforcedSettings = @(
            )
        }
    }
    
    Update-MgPolicyRoleManagementPolicyRule -UnifiedRoleManagementPolicyId $unifiedRoleManagementPolicyId -UnifiedRoleManagementPolicyRuleId $unifiedRoleManagementPolicyRuleId -BodyParameter $params
```

**Terraform file**

Please ensure that the `PowerShell` script is in the same folder as the Terraform code before executing it.

```kotlin
provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    resource "null_resource" "Powershell_script" {
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = <<-EOT
          powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ${path.module}/PIMRole.ps1
        EOT
      }
    }
```

**Reference**: [Update the justification, MFA, and ticketing rules required on activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/how-to-pim-update-rules?tabs=powershell#example-2-update-the-justification-mfa-and-ticketing-rules-required-on-activation)

[Get-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleSetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadmsprivilegedrolesetting?view=azureadps-2.0-preview)

Comment: Thanks, Any updation required in this powershell script according to our environment?

Comment: No, you only need to run the script above.